# Using VBA to create a search form from table based on date combo box in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, type-mismatch

Was wondering if anyone can help me with my code keep getting an error on my Date Due search in table but my text search is working great with Department and Manufacturer. Date_Due is in Date/Time format the error is 3464 Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

```
Private Sub Date_Due_Search_AfterUpdate()

Dim Date_Duelist As String
Date_Duelist = "Select * from Equipment_List where ([Date_Due] = '" & Me.Date_Due_Search & "')"
Me.Equipment_List_subform.Form.RecordSource = Date_Duelist
Me.Equipment_List_subform.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: I'd give `where ([Date_Due] = #" & Me.Date_Due_Search & "#)"` a shot

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! Would of never figured it out if it wasn't for your help.